# How can I send url parameter to php file like permalink in nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, centos7, nginx-config

Recently I moved to Nginx I fixed my all WordPress sites by adding a custom script

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

But now I noticed I had a custom script in the back end folder with its own .htaccess and it stopped working now.

I was using

```
Options -Multiviews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?x=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This .htaccess allows me to send `https://example.com/apps/scripts/api/check_connection`
trail directly into api.php file as a `api.php?x=check_connection`

Now In Nginx I tried

```
# Serves api
location /apps/scripts/api/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?x=$args;  
}
```

But the server is returning 404 for `https://example.com/apps/scripts/api/check_connection` please give me a solution to fix this.

I have no idea how Nginx configs work.

I tried https://winginx.com/en/htaccess and https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx to convert .htaccess to Nginx config but both websites' config does not work for me.

I will be really grateful to find the solution

Comment: `/api.php?x=$args;`  - this is presumably trying to load `/api.php` in the document root, but this would seem to be located at `/apps/scripts/api/api.php`? Try removing the slash prefix (to make it relative), or explicitly including the full path? Also, you want to be passing a _partial_ `$uri`, not `$args`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still no results.

Its returning 404 no matter what.